# Java Hibernate Spring AnnotationException unmapped class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-many

mvn clean install works without any errors, but when i start tomcat6 i get the following error: Caused by:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.xxx.server.entity.app.App.distributions[com.xxx.server.entity.distribution.Distribution]
```

The whole tree is at the end.

I searched the whole day here and in the web but didn't find a working solution for me.

Setup:
I want to do a many to many association with Hibernate between the two classes: App and Distribution:

Distribution.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DISTRIBUTION")
public class Distribution extends xxxEntity {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "APP_DISTRIBUTION", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "distribution_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "app_id") })
    private Set<App> apps;

    }
```

App.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="APP")
public class App extends xxxEntity {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "APP_DISTRIBUTION", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "app_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "distribution_id") })
    private Set<Distribution> distributions;
```

I also tried it with targetEntity.

the mapping is in server-persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />


<bean id="serverPropertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>file:${xxx_server_config_location}/xxx-server.properties
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- Definition of the data source -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${dataSource.driverClass}" />
    <property name="url" value="${dataSource.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${dataSource.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${dataSource.password}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="${dataSource.initialSize}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="${dataSource.maxActive}" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${dataSource.maxIdle}" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="${dataSource.minIdle}" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="false" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="false" />
</bean>

<!-- Starts up Hibernate -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="entityInterceptor">
        <bean class="com.xxx.server.util.hibernate.AuditInterceptor" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${hibernate.batchSize}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <!--
                use log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug in log4j config to show
                SQL
            -->
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hiberhibernate.hbm2ddl.export">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.export}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.outputfilename">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.outputfilename}</prop>


        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.xxx.server.entity.user.AdminUser</value>
            <value>com.xxx.server.entity.app.App</value>
            <value>com.xxx.server.entity.app.AppCategory</value>    
            <value>com.xxx.server.entity.app.AppLanguageSpecific</value>    
            <value>com.xxx.server.entity.device.Device</value>  
            <value>com.xxx.server.entity.device.Vendor</value>
            <value>com.xxx.server.entity.distribution.Distribution</value>
            <value>com.xxx.server.entity.feedback.UserFeedback</value>
            <value>com.xxx.server.entity.info.Info</value>
            <value>com.xxx.server.entity.info.InfoParam</value>
            <value>com.xxx.server.entity.infotype.InfoType</value>
            <value>com.xxx.server.entity.infotype.InfoTypeParam</value>
            <value>com.xxx.server.entity.logging.LoggingEvent</value>
            <value>com.xxx.server.entity.user.User</value>

        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Console output:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appUploadService': Autowiring of fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.xxx.server.dao.AppDao com.xxx.backend.admin.service.impl.AppUploadServiceImpl.appDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appDao' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-server-persistence.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-server-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.xxx.server.entity.app.App.distributions[com.xxx.server.entity.distribution.Distribution]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.xxx.server.dao.AppDao com.xxx.backend.admin.service.impl.AppUploadServiceImpl.appDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appDao' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-server-persistence.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-server-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.xxx.server.entity.app.App.distributions[com.xxx.server.entity.distribution.Distribution]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.injectFields(InjectionMetadata.java:105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:240)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appDao' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-server-persistence.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-server-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.xxx.server.entity.app.App.distributions[com.xxx.server.entity.distribution.Distribution]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:412)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-server-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.xxx.server.entity.app.App.distributions[com.xxx.server.entity.distribution.Distribution]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.xxx.server.entity.app.App.distributions[com.xxx.server.entity.distribution.Distribution]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1071)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:602)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:543)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1148)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:673)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    ... 58 more
02.03.2012 15:47:59 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SCHWERWIEGEND: Error listenerStart
02.03.2012 15:47:59 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SCHWERWIEGEND: Context [/xxx-appstore-admin] startup failed due to previous errors
02.03.2012 15:47:59 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
```

Another strange thing: in the project is already a working ManyToMany realation which works fine:

```
public class Info extends xxxEntity {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_INFO", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "info_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") })
    private Set<User> users;

public class User extends xxxEntity {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_INFO", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "info_id") })
    private Set<Info> infos;
```

I wrote two tests and they run through!!!

```
public class DistributionTest extends BaseDaoTest {
    @Test
    @Transactional
    @Rollback(true)
    public void testDistribution() {
        // Test saving and loading Distribution
        Distribution distribution = DomainCreator.createDistribution("Fedora", "16.01");
        this.distributionDao.save(distribution); 
        assertEquals(distribution, this.distributionDao.findByName("Fedora"));

        // test loading set of distributions
        App app = appDao.findById("a1");
        Set<Distribution> distros = app.getDistributions();
        assertEquals(3, distros.size());
   }
}

public class AppDaoTest extends BaseDaoTest   {
@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback(true)
public void getAppsByDistribution() {
    Distribution distribution = distributionDao.findById("d1");
    Set<App> apps = distribution.getApps();
    assertEquals(4, apps.size());
}
}
```

So I guess the it must be a problem with Tomcat6?

What I also did: deleting everything in the Tomcat deploy directory an publish, but still the same error.

Does anyone have an Idea?

Comment: Have you been renaming/moving your classes?? (especially the App and Distribution)?

Comment: I added the class Distribution. App stayed the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I wrote tests which passed. 
I had the idea that my local tomcat6 is doing something wrong.
So I deployed my changes to another server and there it worked! 
Sorry for bothering you with the wrong question.

Thank you all very much for your help.

Cheers,

Flo

Answer (score 0):

Check Example 3 at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html. So the App mapping should be like,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="APP")
public class App extends xxxEntity {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="apps")
    private Set<Distribution> distributions;
```

Also check if joinColumns and inverseJoinColumns  are configured according to the example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried it but i got the exact same error.
joinColumns and inverseColumns are coming from
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;